# JavaScript date time between search from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Schedule array with start/end date time and its layouts name.

```
let schedule=[
  {
    "start": "2017-10-01 08:00:00",
    "end": "2017-10-01 09:00:00",
    "layout": "layout1.json"
  },
  {
    "start": "2017-10-01 10:00:00",
    "end": "2017-10-01 12:00:00",
    "layout": "layout2.json"
  },
]

let current_time = "2017-10-01 10:30:00";
```

If current dateTime is `**current_time**` in need to get layout name `layout2.json`.
need to search between dateTime from above array using JavaScript.

I have try below code but its not working ..

```
 for (i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++){
   if (schedule[i].start >= current_time && schedule[i].end <= current_time){  
     return schedule[i].layout;
    }
 }
```

Help me, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: You are comparing the time as strings, not date objects. Be sure to make the time values new Date("2017-10-01 10:30:00")

Comment: you are trying to compare string with date time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date to a js Date before comparing.

```
for (i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++){
    if (new Date(schedule[i].start)<= new Date(current_time) && new Date(schedule[i].end) >= new Date(current_time)){  
      return schedule[i].layout;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You had the comperators backwards, corrected it in my answer, and updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmb73598/